# Installing Git in Terminal BUT Password is locked. How do i unlock it?

Tags: bash, terminal, installation

Am trying to install Git via command line but can not enter password. There is an image of a key beside the word password. When i type my password nothing appears in the terminal. How can i enter my password?

Comment: Your password is being entered but not shown.  Just enter your password normally and press enter.

Comment: Thank You :) Yes it worked!